Issue with Upload & Translation drawing file
drawing.pug:
extends ../layouts/_layout.pug

block variables
    - var activePage = 'Drawings';
    - var activeGroup = 'none';

block content
    .app-title
        div
            h1
                i.bi.bi-speedometer
                | #{title}

        ul.app-breadcrumb.breadcrumb
            li.breadcrumb-item
                i.bi.bi-house-door.fs-6
            li.breadcrumb-item
                a(href='#') #{title}

    .row
        .col-md-12
            .tile
                .tile-title-w-btn
                    h3.title List of #{title}
                    p
                        button.btn.btn-primary.icon-btn(type="button", id="addFirmBtn", onclick="openFirmModal('Add', '')", data-bs-toggle="modal", data-bs-target="#modalDialogScrollable")
                            i.bi.bi-plus-square.me-2
                            | Add
                            
                .tile-body
                    .table-responsive
                        table.table.table-hover.table-bordered#sampleTable
                            thead
                                tr
                                    th #
                                    th Drawing Name
                                    th Bucket Name
                                    th Uploded Drawing
                                    th Type
                                    th Documents 
                                    th GEO Cordinates
                                    th Status
                                    th Action
                            tbody

    //- Popup Form
    div#modalDialogScrollable.modal.fade(tabindex="-1")
        div.modal-dialog.modal-dialog-scrollable
            div.modal-content
                div.modal-header
                    h5.modal-title #{modalTitle}
                    button.btn-close(type="button", data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close")
                //- Form Fields
                form#firmForm(method="POST", action="javascript:void(0);", enctype="multipart/form-data")
                    input#clientId(type="hidden" name="clientId" value=session.user.data.client_id)
                    div.modal-body
                        //- Firm Name
                        div.form-group
                            label(for="drawing_name") Drawing Name
                            input#drawing_name.form-control(type="text", placeholder="Enter Drawing Name" name="drawing_name")

                        div.form-group
                            label(for="bucket_id") Bucket
                                select#bucket_id.form-control(name="bucket_id")
                                    option(value="") -- Select Bucket --
                        
                        div.form-group
                            label(for="upload") Upload Drawing
                            input#upload.form-control(type="file" name="upload")

                        div.form-group
                            label(for="drawing_doc") Upload Drawing Doc 
                                small (PDF, PPT only)
                            input#drawing_doc.form-control(type="file" name="drawing_doc")

                        //- Latitude and Longitude
                        div.form-group
                            label Latitude and Longitude
                            table.table.table-hover.table-bordered#latLngTable
                                thead
                                    tr
                                        th Latitude
                                        th Longitude
                                        th Action
                                tbody
                                    tr 
                                        td 
                                            input#latitude.form-control(type="text" name="latitude[]")
                                        td 
                                            input#longitude.form-control(type="text" name="longitude[]")
                                        td 
                                            
                                    tr 
                                        td 
                                            input#latitude.form-control(type="text" name="latitude[]")
                                        td 
                                            input#longitude.form-control(type="text" name="longitude[]")
                                        td 
                                            
                                    tr 
                                        td 
                                            input#latitude.form-control(type="text" name="latitude[]")
                                        td 
                                            input#longitude.form-control(type="text" name="longitude[]")
                                        td 
                                            

                            //- Button to add Latitude and Longitude row
                            button#addLatLngBtn.btn.btn-primary(type="button") Add Latitude/Longitude

                            
                    div.modal-footer
                        button.btn.btn-secondary(type="button", data-bs-dismiss="modal") Close
                        button#saveFirmBtn.btn.btn-primary(type="button", onclick="submitForm()") Save



block specific-js
    block specific-js
        link(rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs5/dt-1.13.4/datatables.min.css")
        
        //- Data table plugin
        script(type='text/javascript', src="/js/plugins/jquery.dataTables.min.js")
        script(type='text/javascript').
            var activeStatus = 1;
            $(document).ready(function() {
                //$('#sampleTable').DataTable();
                loadTableData(activeStatus);

                // Fetch backets from clientMaster/getDepartment
                
                var clientId = $('#clientId').val(); 
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/client/getClientBuckets/' + clientId,
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function(response) {
                        if (response.status === 1) {
                            $('#bucket_id').empty().append('<option value="">-- Select Bucket --</option>');
                            $.each(response.data, function(key, value) {
                                $('#bucket_id').append('<option value="' + value.bucket_id + '">' + value.bucket_name + '</option>');
                            });
                        } else {
                            console.error('Failed to fetch Bucket:', response.error);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        console.error('Error fetching Bucket:', error);
                    }
                });

                // Add Latitude and Longitude row
                $('#addLatLngBtn').click(function() {
                    $('#latLngTable tbody').append(
                        `<tr>
                            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="latitude[]"></td>
                            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="longitude[]"></td>
                            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-row">Remove</button></td>
                        </tr>`
                    );
                });

                // Remove Latitude and Longitude row
                $('#latLngTable').on('click', '.remove-row', function() {
                    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                });
            });

            function loadTableData(event) {
                var url = `/drawing/getDrawing?status=${event}`;
                if(event == '*'){
                    url = `/drawing/getDrawing`;
                }
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function(response) {
                        if (response.status === 1) {
                            var tableData = response.data;
                            populateTable(tableData);
                        } else {
                            console.error('Failed to fetch table data:', response.error);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        console.error('Error fetching table data:', error);
                    }
                });
            }

            function populateTable(data) {
                var tbody = $('#sampleTable tbody');
                tbody.empty(); // Clear existing table body
                if (data && data.length > 0) {
                    data.forEach(function(element, index) {
                        console.log('element', element);
                        var row = $('<tr>');
                        row.append($('<td>').text(index + 1));
                        row.append($('<td>').text(element.drawing_name));
                        row.append($('<td>').text(element.bucket_name));
                        row.append($('<td>').text(element.drawing_upload));
                        row.append($('<td>').text(element.drawing_type));
                        row.append($('<td>').text(element.drawing_doc));
                        row.append($('<td>').text(element.g_cordinates));
                        if(element.is_active == 1){
                            row.append($('<td>').text('Activated'));
                        }else{
                            row.append($('<td>').text('Inactivated'));
                        }
                        
                        var actionBtns = $('<td>');
                        var editBtn = $('<button>').addClass('btn btn-primary icon-btn').attr('type', 'button').attr('onclick', 'openFirmModal(\'Edit\', ' + JSON.stringify(element) + ')').attr('data-bs-toggle', 'modal').attr('data-bs-target', '#modalDialogScrollable').html('<i class="bi bi-pencil me-2"></i>Edit');
                        var statusBtn = $('<button>').addClass('btn btn-' + (element.is_active == 0 ? 'success' : 'danger') + ' icon-btn').attr('type', 'button').attr('onclick', 'StatusChange(' + (element.is_active == 0 ? 1 : 0) + ', ' + JSON.stringify(element) + ')').html('<i class="bi bi-' + (element.is_active == 0 ? 'check-circle' : 'x-circle') + ' me-2"></i>' + (element.is_active == 0 ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'));
                        var trnslateBtn = $('<button>').addClass('btn btn-success icon-btn').attr('type', 'button').attr('onclick', 'getTrtranslation(' + JSON.stringify(element.drawing_id) + ')').html('Trtranslation');
                        actionBtns.append(editBtn);
                        actionBtns.append(statusBtn);
                        actionBtns.append(trnslateBtn);
                        row.append(actionBtns);
                        tbody.append(row);
                    });
                    $('#sampleTable').DataTable();
                } else {
                    tbody.append('<tr><td colspan="9">No data available</td></tr>');
                }
            }

            function openFirmModal(formType, element) {
                var modalTitle = '';
                var formAction = '';
                if (formType === 'Add') {
                    modalTitle = 'Upload Drawing';
                    formAction = '/drawing/addDrawing';
                } else if (formType === 'Edit' && element) {
                    modalTitle = 'Edit Uploaded Drawing';
                    formAction = '/drawing/updateDepartment/' + element.department_id;
                            
                    // Set form field values
                    document.getElementById('department_name').value = element.department_name;
                    document.getElementById('department_desc').value = element.department_desc;
                }
                        
                // Set form action
                document.getElementById('firmForm').action = formAction;
                        
                // Set modal title
                document.querySelector('.modal-title').textContent = modalTitle;
            }
            
            function submitForm() {
                var formAction = document.getElementById('firmForm').action;
                // Collect latitude and longitude points
                var coordinates = [];
                $('#latLngTable tbody tr').each(function() {
                    var latitude = $(this).find('input[name="latitude[]"]').val();
                    var longitude = $(this).find('input[name="longitude[]"]').val();
                    coordinates.push({ lat: latitude, lng: longitude });
                });
                var formData = {
                    drawing_name: document.getElementById('drawing_name').value,
                    bucket_id: document.getElementById('bucket_id').value,
                    g_cordinates: JSON.stringify(coordinates)
                };

                console.log("formData", formData);
                // Send AJAX request
                $.ajax({
                    url: formAction,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: formData,
                    success: function(response) {
                        if (response.status === 1) {
                            var drawing_id = response.data.drawing_id;
                            uploadDrawingDocs(drawing_id);
                        } else {
                            alert('Error: ' + response.message);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        console.error('Error:', error);
                        alert('An error occurred while submitting the form. Please try again later.');
                    }
                });
            }

            function uploadDrawingDocs(drawing_id) {
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('file', document.getElementById('drawing_doc').files[0]);
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/drawing/uploadDrawingDocs/' + drawing_id,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: formData,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function(response) {
                        if (response.status === 1) {
                            uploadDrawings(drawing_id);
                        } else {
                            alert('Error: ' + response.message);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        console.error('Error:', error);
                        alert('An error occurred while submitting document. Please try again later.');
                    }
                });
            }


            function uploadDrawings(drawing_id) {
                var formDrawingData = new FormData();
                formDrawingData.append('file', document.getElementById('upload').files[0]);
                console.log('formDrawingData', formDrawingData);
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/drawing/uploadDrawings/' + drawing_id,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: formDrawingData,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function(response) {
                        if (response.status === 1) {
                            alert(response.message);
                            location.reload();
                        } else {
                            alert('Error: ' + response.message);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        console.error('Error:', error);
                        alert('An error occurred while submitting the drawing. Please try again later.');
                    }
                });
            }


            function getTrtranslation(drawing_id){
                console.log('drawing_id', drawing_id);
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/drawing/uploadDrawingTranslation/' + drawing_id,
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function(response) {
                        if (response.status === 1) {
                            console.log('response', response);
                        } else {
                            console.error('Failed to fetch table data:', response.error);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        console.error('Error fetching table data:', error);
                    }
                });
            }

drawing.controller.js code:
const { DataManagementClient, ModelDerivativeClient } = require('forge-server-utils');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const configAPS = require('../../config');
const { getModels } = require('../../databases/mysql');
const { authenticate } = require('../../services/authenticationService');
const { UtilsServices } = require('../../services/index')
const multer = require('multer');

// Initialize Forge clients
const dataClient = new DataManagementClient(configAPS.credentials);
const derivativeClient = new ModelDerivativeClient(configAPS.credentials);

// Configure multer storage
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'public/uploads/drawing-docs');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        if (!req.params.id) {
            return cb(new Error('Drawing ID is missing'));
        }
        // File name will be drawing_id + current timestamp + original file extension
        const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9);
        cb(null, `${req.params.drawing_id}-${uniqueSuffix}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`);
    }
});
// Configure multer storage for uploadDrawings
const uploadDrawingsStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'public/uploads/drawings');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        if (!req.params.id) {
            return cb(new Error('Drawing ID is missing'));
        }
        // File name will be drawing_id + current timestamp + original file extension
        const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9);
        cb(null, `${req.params.drawing_id}-${uniqueSuffix}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`);
    }
});

// Initialize multer upload for uploadDrawings
const uploadDrawings = multer({ storage: uploadDrawingsStorage }).single('file');
// Initialize multer upload
const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('file');

module.exports = {  
    addDrawing: async (req, res) => {
        let body = req.body;
        let response = { status: 0 }

        if (body.drawing_name) {
            req.body.created_by = req.session.user.data.user_id;
            body.client_id = req.session.user.data.client_id;

            getModels().drawings.build(req.body).save().then(async (drawings) => {
                response.status = 1;
                response.data = drawings.dataValues;
                res.status(200).send(response)
            }).catch((err) => {
                res.status(200).send(UtilsServices.errorHandler(err))
            });
        } else {
            res.send({ status: 0, message: "invalid parameters" })
        }
    },

    uploadDrawingDocs: async (req, res) => {
        let body = req.body;
        let query = { drawing_id: req.params.id };
        let drawing = await getModels().drawings.findOne({ where: query });
        if (!drawing) {
            return res.status(404).json({ status: 0, message: 'Drawing not found' });
        }

        // Call the multer upload middleware
        upload(req, res, async function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Error uploading file:', err);
                return res.status(500).json({ status: 0, message: 'Error uploading file' });
            }

            // Check if file was uploaded
            if (!req.file) {
                return res.status(400).json({ status: 0, message: 'No file uploaded' });
            }

            // File uploaded successfully, you can handle further logic here
            let fileName = req.file.filename;
            let data = { 'drawing_doc': fileName }
            let date = new Date().toISOString().replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/\..+/, '')
            data.updated_at = date;
            drawing.update(data);
            res.status(200).send({
                status: 1,
                message: "Updated successfully!",
                data: drawing
            })
        });
    },

    uploadDrawings: async (req, res) => {
        let body = req.body;
        console.log('req.params.id', req.params.id);
    
        // Call the multer upload middleware
        uploadDrawings(req, res, async function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Error uploading file:', err);
                return res.status(500).json({ status: 0, message: 'Error uploading file' });
            }
    
            // Check if file was uploaded
            if (!req.file) {
                return res.status(400).json({ status: 0, message: 'No file uploaded' });
            }
            
            try {
                let query = { drawing_id: req.params.id };
                let drawing = await getModels().drawings.findOne({ where: query });
                if (!drawing) {
                    return res.status(404).json({ status: 0, message: 'Drawing not found' });
                }

                let query2 = { bucket_id: drawing.bucket_id };
                let bucket = await getModels().buckets.findOne({ where: query2 });
                if (!bucket) {
                    return res.status(404).json({ status: 0, message: 'Bucket not found' });
                }
                
                // Authenticate with Forge
                const token = await authenticate(); // Implement your authentication logic
                // Read the file data
                const fileData = fs.readFileSync(req.file.path);

                // Set the bucket key, object key, and upload options
                const bucketKey = bucket.bucket_name;
                const objectKey = req.file.originalname;
                const options = {}; 
                
                // Upload the file to the Forge bucket
                const uploadedObject = await dataClient.uploadObject(bucketKey, objectKey, fileData, options);
                console.log('Object uploaded successfully:', uploadedObject);

                let urn = Buffer.from(uploadedObject.objectId).toString('base64');
                let pathInArchive = uploadedObject.location;
                // Store the URN in the database
                let fileName = req.file.originalname;
                let data = { 'drawing_upload': fileName, 'drawing_urn': urn, 'drawing_location': pathInArchive }
                let date = new Date().toISOString().replace(/T/, ' ').replace(/\..+/, '')
                data.updated_at = date;
                drawing.update(data);
    
                res.status(200).json({
                    status: 1,
                    message: "File uploaded and translated successfully!",
                    data: { urn }
                });
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error:', error);
                res.status(500).json({ status: 0, message: 'An error occurred', error: error.message });
            }
        });
    },

    uploadDrawingTranslation: async (req, res) => {
        console.log('req.params.id', req.params.id);
        try {
            let query = { drawing_id: req.params.id };
            let drawing = await getModels().drawings.findOne({ where: query });
            if (!drawing) {
                return res.status(404).json({ status: 0, message: 'Drawing not found' });
            }

            let query2 = { bucket_id: drawing.bucket_id };
            let bucket = await getModels().buckets.findOne({ where: query2 });
            if (!bucket) {
                return res.status(404).json({ status: 0, message: 'Bucket not found' });
            }

            const urn = drawing.drawing_urn;
            const pathInArchive = drawing.drawing_location;
            console.log('urn', urn);
            const formats =  [
                { type: 'svf', views: ['2d', '3d'] }, 
                { type: 'obj', views: ['2d', '3d'] },
                { type: 'dwg', views: ['2d', '3d'] },
                { type: 'stl', views: ['2d', '3d'] },
                { type: 'step', views: ['2d', '3d'] },
                { type: 'iges', views: ['2d', '3d'] },
                { type: 'thumbnail', views: ['2d', '3d'] },
                { type: 'fbx', views: ['2d', '3d'] },
                { type: 'ifc', views: ['2d', '3d'] },
                { type: 'f3d', views: ['2d', '3d'] },
                { type: 'pdf', views: ['2d', '3d'] },
            ];                
            const force = true; // or false based on your requirements
            // Trigger the translation process
            const job = await derivativeClient.submitJob(urn, formats, pathInArchive, force);
            console.log('Job', job);

            // Wait for translation to complete
            let translationCompleted = false;
            while (!translationCompleted) {
                const manifest = await derivativeClient.getManifest(urn);
                if (manifest.status === 'success') {
                    console.log('manifestSuccess', manifest);
                    translationCompleted = true;
                } else if (manifest.status === 'failed') {
                    console.log('manifestFailed', manifest);
                    if(manifest.derivatives[0]){
                        console.log('manifestError', manifest.derivatives[0].messages);
                    }
                    throw new Error('Translation failed');
                } else {
                    console.log('manifest', manifest);
                    if(manifest.derivatives[0]){
                        console.log('manifestError', manifest.derivatives[0].messages);
                    }
                    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000)); // Wait for 5 seconds before checking again
                }
            }

            // Translation completed, fetch metadata
            const metadata = await derivativeClient.getMetadata(urn);
            console.log('metadata', metadata);

            // const metadataStream = await derivativeClient.getMetadataStream(urn);
            // console.log('metadataStream', metadataStream);

        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
            res.status(500).json({ status: 0, message: 'An error occurred', error: error.message });
        }
    },
    
};


the issue i am facing is getManifest method
when I upload same file in https://oss-manager.autodesk.io/ it is working fine so I don’t think issue with my uploaded drawing.
so what i want is there is any error what is that error and how i fix it
and if possible i want to get all DBIDs of parts and it properties after successful Translation

Please consider simplifying the code snippet as much as possible. The code that's included at this point is too large and too complex to be useful for any debugging.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Without investigating the code snippet included in the question, what is often a problem is the actual upload process. For example, the file is not uploaded completely, or the contents of the file is malformed. A good way to check this is to use the getObjectDetails endpoint, find the byte size of the uploaded object, and see if it matches the file size of the original file you were uploading.
